# RKRelationshipMapping with Parent Entity Restkit

Tags: restkit

I have a core data relationship mapping shown here:

[image]

This JSON:

```
{
  user: {
    rid: '1234'
    providers: {
       [
         foursquare: {
           rid: '1234'
         },
         facebook: {
           rid: '1234'
         }
       ]
    }
  }
```

Uses this mapping:

```
    RKEntityMapping *foursquareProviderMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"FoursquareProvider" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
foursquareProviderMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"rid"];
[foursquareProviderMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"rid"]];

RKEntityMapping *facebookProviderMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"FacebookProvider" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
facebookProviderMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"rid"];
[facebookProviderMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"rid"]];

RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
userMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"rid"];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"rid"]];
[userMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"providers.foursquare" toKeyPath:@"providers" withMapping:foursquareProviderMapping]];
[userMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"providers.facebook" toKeyPath:@"providers" withMapping:facebookProviderMapping]];
```

This leads to a multiple key path mapping error for the toKeyPath:@"providers"

Is there a correct way to map this? I have full control over the JSON if it needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RKDynamicMapping to solve this problem. First you should change your JSON.

```
{
user: {
rid: '1234'
providers: [
         {
         type: "foursquare"
         rid: '1234'
         },
         {
         type: "facebook"
         rid: '1234'
         }
     ]
  }
}
```

After that use dynamic mapping like this

```
RKEntityMapping *foursquareProviderMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"FoursquareProvider" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
foursquareProviderMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"rid"];
[foursquareProviderMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"rid"]];

RKEntityMapping *facebookProviderMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"FacebookProvider" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
facebookProviderMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"rid"];
[facebookProviderMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"rid"]];

RKDynamicMapping *dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];
[dynamicMapping addMatcher:[RKObjectMappingMatcher matcherWithKeyPath:@"type" expectedValue:@"facebook" objectMapping:facebookProviderMapping]];
[dynamicMapping addMatcher:[RKObjectMappingMatcher matcherWithKeyPath:@"type" expectedValue:@"foursquare" objectMapping:foursquareProviderMapping]];

RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
userMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"rid"];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"rid"]];
[userMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"providers" toKeyPath:@"providers" withMapping:dynamicMapping]];
```